# How to measure negativity for GHZ state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, density-operator

Good day

Can anyone help me to explain how to calculate in detail GHZ state by using negativity formula.

GHZ state given as below:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (\lvert000\rangle +  \lvert111\rangle )$$

I used negativity formula as below:

$$N(\rho_A)=\frac{Tr[\sigma_{A}^\dagger\sigma_{A}]^{1/2}-1}{2}$$

where $\sigma_{A}$ is partial transpose of qubit A by tracing over qubit B and C.

As example, I get the

$$\rho_A=\begin{pmatrix}
1/2 & 0 \\
0 & 1/2 \end{pmatrix}$$.

When I calculate the $N(\rho_A)$, I get the value equal to $0$. It same goes to B and C.

When I want to calculate the negativity for  all three qubits, I used formula below

$$N_{ABC}(\rho)=(N_{A-BC}N_{B-AC}N_{C-AB})^{1/3}$$

with

$$N_{I-JK}=-2\Sigma_i\sigma_i(\rho^{TI})$$

where

$\sigma_i(\rho^{TI})$ being the negative eigenvalues of $\rho^{TI}$, the partial transpose $\rho$ with respect to subsystem $I$.

The result from the paper I read, the value for GHZ-state is equal to $\frac{1}{2}$. It different with my result. I get $0$.

I don't know what the mistake I did and I don't really understand the negativity formula for tripartite.

I really need help to these problem. Can anyone give exact calculate about this.

Thank you very much for helping me.

Comment: Regarding 1: What did you try? Please show your effort! Regarding 2: What is $\sigma_A$?

Comment: I want to calculate GHZ state. From my reading, $\sigma_A$ represent eigenvalues

Comment: If you don't show your effort, you're unlikely to get help.  Also, $\sigma_A$ do NOT represent eigenvalues.  You should start by understanding the formulas you want to use.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch , I already edit my post. Perhaps you can help me to solve my problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: I suggest you start by first trying to compute the negativity of a bi-partite maximally entanged state.

Comment: what u mean by bi-partite maximally entangled state?

Comment: My suggestion is that you start by computing the negativity of the state $(|00\rangle+|11\rangle)/\sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that you are confusing the partial transpose with the partial trace: ``...where $\sigma_A$ is partial transpose of qubit $A$ by tracing over qubit $B$ and $C$.'' They are not the same.

The idea of the negativity comes from the criterion for entanglement based on the partial transpose. It states that if, by transposing the indices (row and columns) for one of the two partites, while leaving the other one unchanged, one obtains a positive matrix (one with only positive eigenvalues), then the state is not entangled. This only works for distillable entanglement though. Hence, negative eigenvalues indicate entanglement. The negativity is therefore an indication of (an upper bound for) distillable entanglement.

So when you start with an $(MN)\times (MN)$ dimensional density matrix and you do the partial trace (say over $N$ degrees of freedom) you'll end up with an $M\times M$ dimensional density matrix. On the other hand, if you do the partial transpose you'll just interchange the indices of one of the partites and you'll still have an $(MN)\times (MN)$ dimensional density matrix.

I think if you do the partial transpose instead of the partial trance you won't get zero anymore.

*Mathematics*:

To understand how the partial transpose works, it may help to express the density matrix as a density *tensor*, which can be defined by
$$\hat{\rho}=\sum_{mnpq} |m\rangle |p\rangle \rho_{mp}^{nq} \langle n| \langle q| . $$
To convert this back into a matrix one can combine the upper (lower) indices to indicate the columns (rows) of the matrix.

The partial transpose is now simply performed by interchanging one upper index with its corresponding lower index
$$ \rho_{mp}^{nq} \rightarrow \rho_{mq}^{np} . $$

*Example*:

Consider the Bell state $(|0\rangle |1\rangle + |1\rangle |0\rangle)/\sqrt{2}$. The density matrix would be

$$ \rho = \frac{1}{2}\left[ \begin{array}{cccc} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\  0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{array} \right] $$
This matrix has only one eigenvalue which is equal to 1.

The partial transpose is given by 
$$ \rho^{\Gamma} = \frac{1}{2}\left[ \begin{array}{cccc} 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{array} \right] $$
This matrix now has 4 eigenvalues: $1/2,1/2,1/2,-1/2$. Note that one of them is negative. The negativity is given by minus the sum of the negative eigenvalues. Hence, negativity = $1/2$.

(Perhaps you should just check this calculation. I did it rather quickly.)

Comment: Can you give me an example